# Create an invite link with timezone and GUID

Tags: google-calendar-api, icalendar

I've found a fair number of examples on how to create a simple link that, if someone clicks on it, will create an invite in their Google calendar.

But what I have not been able to find is what parameter do I set for:

1. The `dates` timezone.
2. The event `UID` (so that a later updated invite will replace the first link)

??? - thanks - dave